# What focal length do I need to get the same field of view as an iPhone SE?

Tags: lens, focal-length, iphone, field-of-view

I have a FujiFilm camera (mirrorless crop) with a 35mm lens while iPhone SE has a 4mm lens.

What focal length lens do I need for it to get the same field of view as on the iPhone SE?

Comment: You might want to include the sensor size of your fuji cam. Otherwise we will have to guess it is APS-C.

Answer (score 13):

According to [this](https://www.phonearena.com/phones/Apple-iPhone-SE_id10001) the iPhone SE has an 29mm-equivalent lens, so on a Fuji with a 23.6x15.6 sensor (Fuji XT-3)(crop factor 1.53) you need a 29/1.53=19mm lens for the same field of view.

Comment: Minor note though: the XT-3 has a 3:2 aspect ratio, where the iPhone SE has a 4:5 aspect ratio. As such, although a 19 mm lens may give roughly the same angle of view across the diagonal, it won't show exactly the same angle of view horizontally or vertically.